# Adding multiple MKPolyline from loop

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

strange thing happening here.

I have a FOR loop wich tries to add multiple polylines from locations in an NSArray.

The code used in the loop is this

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
    float lat1 = locationDep.coordinate.latitude;
    float lat2 = locationDest.coordinate.latitude;

    float lon1 = locationDep.coordinate.longitude;
    float lon2 = locationDest.coordinate.longitude;

    coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, lon1); 
    coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat2, lon2);

    MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
    [self.worldMap addOverlay:myPolyline];
```

I've implemented the delegate method as following:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay{
// create a polygonView using polygon_overlay object
MKPolylineView *polyLine = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];

polyLine.lineWidth = 5;
// apply stroke & fill color
polyLine.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86/255.0f green:156/255.0f blue:203/255.0f alpha:1.0f];


return polyLine;
}
```

The map delegate is set to self... however...

The polylines never appear on the map!!

I use the same locations from the NSArray to set pin Annotations, and these do appear, so the locations are valid.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the for-loop called from?  Make sure worldMap is not nil at the addOverlay line.  Where is the code that adds the annotations for those locations?  Log or step through the code and verify that the coordinates are still the same and valid before calling addOverlay.

Comment: Hi, Anna. How can I check if worldmap is nil? Just NSlog it? The annotations are added two lines above the code that I posted. So there should be no difference right?

Comment: Yes just `NSLog(@"worldMap=%@", worldMap);`.  Are the annotations also added to worldMap?

Comment: Hi Anna, worldmap is not nil. And the annotations are also added to worldMap indeed.. It's really strange. Looks like the coordinates don't live it through to the overlay method. If I replace the coordinates with ordinary hardcoded floats then everything is fine and the paths get drawn... mystery!